# Request some time got "The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ssl

I have two .Net application docker container on two servers communicating with each other using Api with no problems until a few days ago, some times the request received ssl error about **"The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid"** (it happens for 1-2 minutes and then everything is normal again). Our ssl certificate has not expired yet and I also checked the times on each server and all is good. Is there any other cause for this error?

Answer (score 2):

The root certificate `IdentTrust DST Root CA X3` was expired 30 Sep 2021 - it was used to sign `R3` certs from Let's Encrypt which is probably used in your case.

This year Let's Encrypt moved to `ISRG Root X1` cert which expires in 2035 and it's used for cross-signed cert chain.

So there might be two causes of issue:

1. Old version of OpenSSL which does not support cross-signed certs
2. `ISRG Root X1` is untrusted in your environment

I faced to same problem with `public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:5.0` image from AWS. Its ca-certificates weren't up-to-date.

**The solution** that worked for me is really simple, just add this line in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN yum update ca-certificates -y
```